# app engine bulkloader post_import_function - how to call method on entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

Trying to use python GeoModel class and the bulkloader.   I'm calling the following `post_import_function` which works fine and the entity is updated with the location field set properly.

```
def post_process_obj(input_dict, entity_instance, bulkload_state):
    entity_instance['location'] = db.GeoPt(entity_instance['latitude'], entity_instance['longitude'])
    return entity_instance
```

But what I need to do is call `entity_instance.update_location()` on the entity before it saves to the data store.  The `entity_instance` though is an Entity, not a subclass of GeoModel so I'm not clear how to do this.  There was a post a while back that said inline the code or call a function and pass the entity to it but I don't know what that was supposed to mean.

Thanks for any help/sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this - as you observed, you're dealing with an `Entity`, not an instance of your model. The only option is to take the code that you want to execute it, copy-and-paste it, and modify it to work with an entity instead.

Comment: Thanks Nick - i pretty much discovered that although I found a post from Matthew Blaine saying that you can use model instead of "kind" in the bulkloader.yaml although I didn't actually find any documentation.    Anyway I fixed my problem by not using GeoHash and porting to use geobox.py instead which seems to solve my geoquery requirements pretty nicely.